# How can i make content of an css table responsive

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, css-tables

I am trying to make the contents of a css table to be responsive and I'm not having any luck.
Sorry if i made any mistake in this trade, I am new to stack overflow.
This is my html table:

```
<div class="branduriTable">
  <div class="bodyTable">
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Alfa Romeo</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Audi</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">BMW</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Jaguar</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Lancia</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Mercedes</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Ford</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Renault</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Jeep</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Skoda</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Ferrari</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand">Volkswagen</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css code:

```
.branduriTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.randTable {
  display: table-row;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.cellTable {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.bodyTable {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.brandLogo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 20px;
  background: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.denumireBrand {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0033cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

What did i mis ? I'm also new to coding

[Jsfiddle exemple here](https://jsfiddle.net/ihopethisusernameisgood/k6uz1bcn/)

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong in this example. The table looks to be responding just fine to resizing the window. Are you asking specifically how to use responsive media queries (which your example does not have)?

Comment: when i open this table on mobile it looks realy untidy

Comment: can i place a link to my page?

Comment: yah do that @I0sif

Comment: @Jon Uleis I0sif just wants to make it look good like pop out or something

Comment: https://www.bbcauto.ro/ ....i don't now why it looks so messy on a mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem starts when the device screen reaches on 512px or below.

So here's my solution(which is completely responsive):

```
1. First of all you need to add this viewport meta tag just after the `head` tag starts.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 


2. and then add this media query in your `style.css` file
@media (max-width:512px){.cellTable { display: block; padding: 5px; }}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hello first of all ty for your time and for trying to help me :), but as a new wordpress user where do i insert this two line codes... sorry for my noob question

Comment: Just edited my answer . Add viewport meta tag inside the head tag(Just after the head starts) and add that media query in custom.css file or style.css file

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To make it responsive you could add this CSS:

```
 div {
  transition: .2s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(0,-2px,0);
}
```

The Code snippet:

```css
.branduriTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.randTable {
  display: table-row;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.cellTable {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.bodyTable {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.brandLogo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 20px;
  background: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.denumireBrand {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0033cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
div {
  transition: .2s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(0,-2px,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="branduriTable">
  <div class="bodyTable">
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Alfa Romeo</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Audi</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">BMW</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Jaguar</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">
        <a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Lancia</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Mercedes</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Ford</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Renault</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Jeep</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Skoda</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="randTable">
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Ferrari</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable"><a href="" class="brandLogo" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;"><img src="" alt=""></a><a href="" class="denumireBrand" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">Volkswagen</a></div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cellTable">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- DivTable.com -->
```

Comment: Take a look at you code again because it works fine in the code snippet. @I0sif

Comment: take a look at your code because the code snippet works @I0sif

Comment: @T.Bragg "Responsive", as in responsive design, refers to a page that adjusts its sizing and layout to fit the window/screen it's in. You added shadow on cursor hover states - that's interactive, but not responsive.

Comment: You can't really have interactivity on mobile because there is no mouse